# ScrollView/TextView not displaying all data when layout_gravity is set

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, scrollview

Whenever the `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` attribute is set on the style xml sheet, the text seems to be cut off at the top, and extra blank lines appear at the bottom. I have set this in order to auto-scroll to the bottom when there is too much text to display. This is hosted in a `DialogFragment`.

Note: the text being displayed is from `TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml())`, with newlines being done as `< br>` if that matters. The a's printed are just test data.

On debugging the TextView, it appears the data is there (in the mText variable), but it just doesn't display.

Dialog xml sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/status_olcr_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/status_olcr_ok"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:clickable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

On screen display of what is happening (but shouldn't):

[image: Scrolling to the top (wrong)]

[image: Scrolling to the bottom (wrong)]

And this is what should be happening (when there is no layout_gravity attribute):

[image: Scrolling to the top (correct)]

[image: Scrolling to the bottom (correct)]

Any idea of whats happening?

Update: I have turned on 'Show layout margins' and the TextView is rendered above the ScrollView bounds (or other way around).. See below images:

[image: Update: Scrolling to the top]

[image: Update: Scrolling to the bottom]

Comment: post the xml with gravity set

Comment: why you are setting `gravity` without setting `weight_sum` for parent.

Comment: @Gordak Not sure what you mean sorry, the gravity is set under the header `<TextView android:id="@+id/status_olcr_text" android:layout_gravity="bottom">`

Comment: @ViswanathL I think the Google docs say somewhere that its not required as it will be calculated from the child views. See here: [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum)

Comment: @marco9999 u didn't see all childs in the documentation. Here you have weight only for one child. Which is wrong

Comment: @ViswanathL Ok I have tried with `android:weightSum="1"`applied on the parent `LinearLayout` of the ScrollView and I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with this solution, although I still don't understand what was going on in the first place...

Within the relevant DialogFragment:

```
scroll = (ScrollView)getView().findViewById(R.id.scroll);
scroll.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a RelativeLayout, where you can set the scroll view to top of parent and button linerar layout to bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/llButton"
    android:alignParentTop="true"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/status_olcr_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llButton"
    android:alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/status_olcr_ok"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:clickable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't work unfortunately.. Same problem as in the question. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Inside textView Tag use :

```
android:layout_gravity="top"
```